# data analysis of java bytecode

Tags: jvm, data-analysis, bytecode

I am working on a java bytecode analyse project, which writes in c

The current stage is to write a stack simulator to simulate the state of class files being executed in the jvm virtual machine.

After processing the basic block of each method, and creating the control flow graph,
I found a problem, which is my guess:

- Is the stack empty after each basic block executed?
- Or when each branch is converging, no matter which branch goes to the
  next basic block, the content on the stack will be the **same**?

eg:

```
 public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
descriptor: ([Ljava/lang/String;)V
flags: (0x0009) ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_STATIC
Code:
  stack=2, locals=3, args_size=1
     0: sipush        2000
     3: istore_1
     4: iload_1
     5: sipush        200
     8: if_icmple     22
    11: getstatic     #7                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    14: ldc           #13                 // String demo
    16: invokevirtual #15                 // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    19: goto          26
    22: invokestatic  #21                 // Method age:()I
    25: pop
    26: bipush        100
    28: istore_2
    29: return
```

i called Method age:()I, which return an int value, after next basic block, the compiler add a pop at 25 to clear oprand stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the stack empty after each basic block executed?

This is specified in section [2.6.4. Normal Method Invocation Completion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.6.4) of the JVM specification:

> The current frame (§2.6) is used in this case to restore the state of the invoker, including its local variables and operand stack, with the program counter of the invoker appropriately incremented to skip past the method invocation instruction.

So, when returning, the stack needs to be cleaned up to make sure anything pushed to it is popped back.

However, the JVM itself doesn't have a concept of blocks, this is only in the Java *language* (there are also `goto` instructions in the bytecode). So, the language can generate bytecode leaving elements on the stack when returning and the JVM should clean that up.

However, for other blocks, it needs to make sure that type checking still works. It no execution path, it should be possible that you are e.g. pushing an `int` and then treating it as an `Object` as I understood it.

I think the relevant part of the specification should be in [4.10.1.6. Type Checking Methods with Code](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1.6):

> A merged code stream is type safe relative to an incoming type state T if it begins with an instruction I that is type safe relative to T, and I satisfies its exception handlers (see below), and the tail of the stream is type safe given the type state following that execution of I.
> `NextStackFrame` indicates what falls through to the following instruction. For an unconditional branch instruction, it will have the special value afterGoto. ExceptionStackFrame indicates what is passed to exception handlers.

And regarding

> Or when each branch is converging, no matter which branch goes to the next basic block, the content on the stack will be the **same**?

I don't think it needs to be exactly the same but it should not lead to type checking violation. If not, class file verification will probably fail.

Comment: Catch is a special case and is not considered. The jvm will push an exception object on the oprand stack, and each catch start with astore_<n>. I have already dealt with this.

What I want to know is whether statements like if statement and for statement are as I guessed.

Comment: Yeah I am talking about normal control flow statements. Have I mentioned exception tables or similar anywhere?

Comment: By [4.10.2.2. The Bytecode Verifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.2.2): "The next instruction, if the current instruction is not an unconditional control transfer instruction (for instance, goto, return, or athrow). Verification fails if it is possible to "fall off" the last instruction of the method. " and "The target(s) of a conditional or unconditional branch or switch. " so merging should also take place when using control flow statements in the corresponding Java code.

Comment: To provide a simple real life case, `System.out.println(Math.random() > 0.5? "yes": "no");` has two branches merging with a string on the operand stack, to be passed to the `println` method. By the way, the example of `int` and `boolean` is a bad one, as the bytecode does not distinguish between these types for most purposes, so pushing an `int` and then treating it as a `boolean` is possible. Pushing an `int` and trying to treat it as a `float` would be a different beast.

Comment: @Holger AFAIK There are some things where it makes a difference. For example, you cannot assign a `boolean` to `5` and I think the verifier checks that. But yes, I guess there are other types making more sense.

Comment: That would require the verifier to predict every int value beforehand, to be able to preclude the value 5, which is not possible. See for example [the `putfield` instruction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se21/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.putfield) where the type matters: “*If the value is of type int and the field descriptor type is boolean, then the int value is narrowed by taking the bitwise AND of value and 1, resulting in value'. The referenced field in objectref is set to value'.*” So it simply stores the lowest bit of the value on the stack into the boolean field.